# Inline query has too many rows for direct assignment, use FOR loop

Tags: apex, soql, query, queryexception

I am receiving an error stated above on line 26**(listAccount1)**, can anyone guide me on how to solve it?

```
public class FRB_UpdateExceptionsforBatch
{

  public static void FRB_Exceptions(){
   string FRBRecordTypeID = utility.getFRBProfileNameLabel();
      List<Account> lstAccount = new List<Account>();
        List<Account> lstAccount1 = new List<Account>();
        List<Account> lstAccount2 = new List<Account>();
        List<Account> lstAccount3 = new List<Account>();
   lstAccount = [Select id,FRB_Firm_Check__c,Number_of_Exception__c,Number_of_exceptions_under_4_6_bucket__c,Number_of_exceptions_under_7_10_bucket__c,Number_of_exceptions_under_11_19_bucket__c,(select id,Account_Standing__c from Process_Adherence_Monitoring__r  where Status__C != 'Closed' AND  recordtypeId =: FRBRecordTypeID AND Account_Standing__c = '0-3 Days (Green - New Exception)' ) FROM Account WHERE FRB_Firm_Check__c = TRUE];
    if(lstAccount.size()>0){
          for( Account acc : lstAccount )
          {
              List<Process_Adherence_Monitoring__c> lstCont = acc.Process_Adherence_Monitoring__r;

              acc.Number_of_Exception__c = lstCont.size();
              acc.FRB_Firm_Check__c = true;
          }

          update lstAccount;
    }


      //To update 4-6 bucket

    lstAccount1 = [select Id, Name,FRB_Firm_Check__c, Number_of_exceptions_under_4_6_bucket__c,(select id,Account_Standing__c from Process_Adherence_Monitoring__r  where Status__C != 'Closed' AND  recordtypeId =: FRBRecordTypeID AND Account_Standing__c = '4-6 Days (Yellow - Outside Correction Timeframe)' ) from Account where FRB_Firm_Check__c = TRUE];

      if(lstAccount1.size()>0){
          for( Account acc : lstAccount1 )
          {
              List<Process_Adherence_Monitoring__c> lstCont1 = acc.Process_Adherence_Monitoring__r;               
              acc.Number_of_exceptions_under_4_6_bucket__c= lstCont1.size();
              acc.FRB_Firm_Check__c = true;
          }

          update lstAccount1 ;
      }


      //To update 6-11 bucket

       lstAccount2 =  [select Id, Name,FRB_Firm_Check__c, Number_of_exceptions_under_7_10_bucket__c,(select id,Account_Standing__c from Process_Adherence_Monitoring__r  where Status__C != 'Closed' AND  recordtypeId =: FRBRecordTypeID AND Account_Standing__c = '7-10 Days (Orange - Approaching Critical Timeframe)' ) from Account where FRB_Firm_Check__c = TRUE];

      if(lstAccount2.size()>0){
          for( Account acc : lstAccount2 )
          {
              List<Process_Adherence_Monitoring__c> lstCont2 = acc.Process_Adherence_Monitoring__r;

              acc.Number_of_exceptions_under_7_10_bucket__c= lstCont2.size();
              acc.FRB_Firm_Check__c = true;
          }
          update lstAccount2 ;
      }

      //To update 11 bucket

          lstAccount3 =  [select Id, Name,FRB_Firm_Check__c, Number_of_exceptions_under_11_19_bucket__c,(select id,Account_Standing__c from Process_Adherence_Monitoring__r  where Status__C != 'Closed' AND  recordtypeId =: FRBRecordTypeID AND Account_Standing__c = '11-19 Days (Red - Immediate Correction Required)' ) from Account where FRB_Firm_Check__c = TRUE];

      if(lstAccount3.size()>0){
          for( Account acc : lstAccount3 )
          {
              List<Process_Adherence_Monitoring__c> lstCont3 = acc.Process_Adherence_Monitoring__r;

              acc.Number_of_exceptions_under_11_19_bucket__c= lstCont3.size();
              acc.FRB_Firm_Check__c = true;
          }                   
          update lstAccount3 ;
      }

    }  
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You get this error when you have a child list that is too large. Have a look at **[SOQL For Loops](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_loops_for_SOQL.htm)**:

> - You might get a `QueryException` in a SOQL for loop with the message `Aggregate query has too many rows for direct assignment, use FOR loop`. This exception is sometimes thrown when accessing a large set of child records (200 or more) of a retrieved sObject inside the loop, or when getting the size of such a record set. For example, the query in the following SOQL for loop retrieves child contacts for a particular account. If this account contains more than 200 child contacts, the statements in the for loop cause an exception.
>
>   ```
>   for (Account acct : [SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Contacts) 
>                       FROM Account WHERE Id IN ('<ID value>')]) { 
>       List<Contact> contactList = acct.Contacts; // Causes an error
>       Integer count = acct.Contacts.size(); // Causes an error
>   }
>   ```
>
> To avoid getting this exception, use a for loop to iterate over the child records, as follows.
>
> ```
> for (Account acct : [SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Contacts) 
>                     FROM Account WHERE Id IN ('<ID value>')]) { 
>     Integer count=0;
>     for (Contact c : acct.Contacts) {
>         count++;
>     }
> }
> ```

So in your case, you should be able to change this line:

```
List<Process_Adherence_Monitoring__c> lstCont1 = acc.Process_Adherence_Monitoring__r;
```

And instead use a `for` loop:

```
List<Process_Adherence_Monitoring__c> lstCont1 = new List<Process_Adherence_Monitoring__c>();
for (Process_Adherence_Monitoring__c child : acc.Process_Adherence_Monitoring__r)
    lstCont1.add(child);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion , but even If I write a separate query on child object I am getting an error of more than 50000 records.Can I apply future method?

Comment: Um. Yes you may be able to make it work with a future method. It looks like batch processing may be more appropriate if you're seeing that volume, though.

Answer (score 1):

One also can provoke this error in a line of code that has no queries at all. For instance, in a Batchable and Schedulable class MyBatch, our Schedulable.execute() method sets a batch size of 200.

```
 Database.executeBatch(new MyBatch(), 200);
```

The Batchable.execute() method passes the entire list to a function in a helper class:

```
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> myScope) {
    List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();
    accountsToUpdate.addAll(MyHelper.myChooser(myScope));
```

Sometimes the helper function throws an error at the call to myUpdater:

```
 public static List<Account> myChooser(List<Account> accs) {

    for(Account acct : accs) {
        Account beforeAccountUpdate = new Account( Id = acct.Id,  etc );
        myUpdater(acct);     // Stack Trace shows this line throws the error
        etc
```

The query used to create the QueryLocator in the start() method does indeed have a subquery in the SELECT clause, joining Account records with Subscription records.
We can reduce the batch size and keep the query the same, which will eliminate most occurrences of the error. Or, a more rigorous approach: remove the subquery and re-write everything to run another query (FROM Subscription) for each account, and pass Lists and Maps around to all the helper functions.
The point is, any handling of a query result set from a query with a subquery can throw this error.

This behavior seems a bit wrong to me. It would be more understandable if the error were thrown when the QueryLocator was set.

It would be nice if there were a documented way for the coder to know whether the query result set is too large.